# Scraping second page in Python gives Data of first Page

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Scraping the second page in Python gives Data of the first Page. 
Here is the concerned a part of the code :

```
browser.get("https://XXXXXXXXX/0_9b34?P=2")

innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")      #type = str    #returns the inner HTML as a string
Eroom_M7_htmlpage = innerHTML

soup = BeautifulSoup(Eroom_M7_htmlpage, 'html.parser')      #type = bs4.BeautifulSoup
htmlprettified = soup.prettify()                            #type = str

project_items = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'headers' : 'ID Item'})
```

I would appreciate if the answers are beginner friendly as I'm just a 3 months Python self-learner.
Please I really need help on this matter to finish my project :( 
ps : I saw two articles about this but didn't help/understand.

Comment: Not a selenium expert, but I guess you probably have to wait for the browser to actually _load_ the page before you access its HTML code. Anyway, if you want better answers that just a stab in the dark, you'll have to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")      #type = str    #returns the inner HTML as a string
Eroom_M7_htmlpage = innerHTML
```

You should be returning the page_source instead of the javascript response

`.page_source` is the method you want to use.

So execute whatever JavaScript you want but then capture the HTML

```
Eroom_M7_htmlpage = browser.page_source
```

instead of `innerhtml` docs ---> [**HERE**](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source)

A basic example of the Selenium usage.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--test-type")
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://python.org')

html = driver.page_source
print(html)
```

> It will output the webpage source, which is stored in the variable
>   html.